# why sqlite doesn't create my database even it has been checked in phpinfo() as it is enabled

Tags: php, database, sqlite

```
<?php 
$db = new SQLite3('phpdb.sqlite');
?>
```

**Why is it giving a fatal error although SQLite enabled?

     I even checked the php.ini file and made changes as:

     sqlite3.extension_dir = "D:\PHP\xampp\php\ext"**

[checked information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0x00.png)

The error reads:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in
>   D:\PHP\xampp\htdocs\midun\OOP\Chap2\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in D:\PHP\xampp\htdocs\midun\OOP\Chap2\index.php on line 4

*(Additional information: I set an environment variable in C:\sqlite that's where I put the sqlite.exe file)*

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database, which doesn't seem to apply to your SQLite question, so I've removed the 'phpmyadmin' tag.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Isaac Bennetch.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 as part of the PDO abstraction layer is not the same as SQLite3 as a "Vendor Specific Database Extensions". You can however use SQLite3 through PDO, see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thank gentlemen. I made it like this. its creating database now.                                                                            $db = new PDO("sqlite:D:/PHP/xampp/htdocs/midun/OOP/database.sqlite");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
$db = new \SQLite3('phpdb.sqlite');
```

instead of

```
$db = new SQLite3('phpdb.sqlite');
```

I suppose that SQLite3 is in [Global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)